# How to show hidden div of another page after redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi i am redirecting one page to another...here is my code

```
 <div class="dash-mdt-details l2">
 <div class="dash-md-tab-row l2 pull-right">
 <a href = "modules.html">   <i class="ico-charcoaldash pull-left">&nbsp;</i>Network 1
 </a> </div>
  <div class="dash-md-tab-row l2 pull-right">
  <a href = "modules.html">   <i class="ico-charcoaldash pull-left">&nbsp;</i>Network 2
    </a>  </div>
    </div>
```

It is succesfully redirected in modules.html but i want to redirected it at particular hidden tag

this is hidden tag which i want to open directly  from modules.html

```
 <div class="dash-mdt-details l1" style="display:none; margin-top: 30px;">
  <div class="module-row module-tab module-details pull-right" style="font-weight:bold;">
            <b>Details:</b><br>
<div id="module-tab-details" style="color:#cc0000;padding-left:10px;background-color: #f7f7f7;border-top: solid 1px #000000;">
                   Network connection disconnected
    </div>
    <div class="module-tabs-details-description pull-right" style="width: 95%;display: block;">
                     <b>Suggested steps:</b><br>
             <ol style="color:Orange; font-weight=bold;">
             <li><div style="color:black";>Step one to resolve the issue. Try this one first!</div></li>
                                                                <li><div style="color:black";>Second Step to resolve the issue. Try this one first!</div></li>
                                                            </ol><br>
                                                            <img src="images/icons/icon-charcoalarrow.png"> <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#commentBox">Add Comments &nbsp; <img src="images/icons/icon-chat.png"></a><br>
                                                            <img src="images/icons/icon-charcoalarrow.png"> <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fetchData">Update / Test Data</a><br>&nbsp;<br>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <span class="grey-line"></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
```

what should i do to show the content of the hidden tag directly after the redirect?

Comment: append a parameter as the query string like `<a href = "modules.html?hidden=false">`, check whether the url contains the param from `modules.html`, if it contains it then make the div visible…

Comment: do you mean "show the content of the hidden tag" after the redirection?

Comment: @Totò exactlly what you understand

Comment: Instead of redirecting why can't you capture the click event on that particular link and show or hide the target div

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Javascript here. Can pull it off with just CSS:

1. Give an `id` to your target `div` in `modules.html`, say `divId`,
2. Add a `:target` style to your CSS in `modules.html`,
3. Change the relevant link to `<a href="modules.html#divId">`

*CSS (for modules.html):*

```
#divId:target {
    display: block;
}
```

*Note*: It is advisable to not have embedded styles. So in your case it would be better if you could move your `display:none; margin-top: 30px;` style to the main CSS of that page.

Comment: I've been doing this a long time and I never knew about the :target pseudo class. Wish I had more up votes to give. He/she'll probably need to move `display: none;` off the `style` attribute and into the css file though, right?

Comment: @gwcoffey: you're right. its always better to *not* have embedded styles. thanks for pointing out. shall add that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** See @abhitalks answer. It is better.

I'm going to go out on a limb here and assume:

1. When you say "redirect" you mean "link". (Are you actually redirecting? Or do you just mean you click the "Network 1" link and it goes to `modules.html`?)
2. When you say "hidden tag" you mean the `<div>` that is hidden (`display: none;`)

And therefore, what you're asking is:

> How can I show the hidden div immediately when I link to the page?

If that is what you mean, you can do this:

**First:** Change your link to `<a href="modules.html#show">...</a>`

**Second:** Put a little javascript on the `modules.html` page:

```
$(document).ready({
   if (window.location.hash == "#show") {
      $(".dash-mdt-details").show();
   }
});
```

This will check the url to see if it has the `#show` on the end. If it does, it will show the hidden `div`.

Note: You can change `#show` to anything you want. Just change it in both places. You can also target different elements by passing different `#whatever` in each link.

Comment: this *is* a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass DOM information in query string.like this:

```
modules.html?showele=dash-mdt-details
```

and on dom ready in page 2, show the hidden element and scroll to that element using:

```
$("."+$.url().param('showele')).show();
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(".'+$.url().param('showele')+'").offset().top},'slow');
```